# How to use adjacent_find with string C++

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, compare, string-comparison

I am attempting to write a function that returns true if there are 2 adjacent characters in a string that are both digits. However with the code I have I keep getting weird errors of the form:

*c:\mingw\include\c++\6.2.0\bits\stl_algo.h:950:21:
required from '_ForwardIterator std::__adjacent_find(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _BinaryPredicate) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _BinaryPredicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter]'*

Therefore I am looking for either a solution or a different way round what I have already written.
Here is my code:

```
bool deriv2::compare(char a, char b){
  if (isdigit(a) == true && isdigit(b) == true){
      return true;
  }
  else return false;
}

bool deriv2::filter(string word){
  string::iterator it;
  it = adjacent_find (++it, word.end(), compare);
  if (it!=word.end()){
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Methods take a hidden parameter that points to an object of the class theyre a method of. Therefore your compare function does not have the right signature (and needs an instance of the class to be called). Either make it a free function, or making it static should work too. Alternatively you could pass a functor or a lambda.

Comment: [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93ffd3242fc457af) modified from cppreference

Comment: making it a free function worked ! could you post your comment as an answer to the question so i can mark it as a solution? thanks buddy

Comment: `it = adjacent_find (++it ...`? Undefined behavior. Also, `it` has no meaningful value at the point of this call, so this does not do anything sensible. Just use `it = adjacent_find(word.begin(), word.end(), ...)` with your comparator.

Comment: yeah i saw ++it online somewhere when looking up how to use adjacent and thought i'd try using it but now that i think about it it doesn't make sense, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also, don't mix C-style booleans and C++ booleans. `isdigit(a)` returns 0 if `a` is not a digit, and returns **a non-zero value** if it is. The code `isdigit(a) == true` compares the value returned by `isdigit` with 1. If `isdigit` returns 2, which still means that the value is a digit, that comparison will fail. Change it to `if (isidigit(a) && isdigit(b)`. The compiler treats non-zero values in booleans contexts as true.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your `compare` method was declared it could have been the source of the compile error. It important that the binary predicate, i.e. `compare`, passed is *not* a member function. Running the program below should have a exit code of `1`.

As a side note, the `filter` function can also be made `static` in this example, but I left it so so it's easy to reproduce without `static` on the `compare` function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

struct deriv2
{
   static bool compare(char a, char b);
   bool filter(std::string const& word) const;
};
bool deriv2::compare(char a, char b)
{
   using std::isdigit;
   return isdigit(a) && isdigit(b);
}
bool deriv2::filter(std::string const& word) const
{
   using std::adjacent_find;
   return adjacent_find(word.begin(), word.end(), compare) != word.end();
}

int main()
{
   deriv2 d;
   return d.filter("ab34cd");
}
```